# Cache And Compare Files In C#

Tags: c#, string, text, caching, web

Ok, I'm trying to make an application for an online Radio Station.

I have it set to read the song title and artist and write it to a text file on the webserver.

I want to have the application store the text in a string or a cache, and then reread it every 15 seconds and if it isn't the same then update the info box.

Where the text is stored:
http://xcastradio.com/stats/nowplaying.txt

I don't need it coded for me. I would just like to know how to store text in a string from a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the example for [`System.Net.WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx).

Pulled from those docs (and modified for your applcation):

```
public String GetData(String url) {
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    String data = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
    return data;
}
```

Call it as:

```
String data = GetData("http://xcastradio.com/stats/nowplaying.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)/[`HttpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx), use [`GetResponseStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx), read it until no more bytes can be read, and put that into a byte array.

After you have the string, you then open a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) to a local file, and write that byte array with the [`Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.write.aspx) method.